# check constraint violated temporal

Tags: sql, oracle, temporal

My table definition

```
CREATE TABLE PROVISION_HIST
(
      card_nbr             number(9) primary key,
      provision_loc_cd          varchar2(2),
      start_ts                  timestamp(6),
      end_ts                    timestamp(6),
      last_updt_ts              timestamp(6),
      provision_meta_data       xmltype,
      unprovision_meta_data     xmltype,
      PERIOD FOR user_valid_time (start_ts, end_ts)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (end_ts)
(  
   PARTITION PROVISION_HIST_P0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('10-01-2014', 'MM-DD-YYYY')),
   PARTITION PROVISION_HIST_P1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('11-01-2014', 'MM-DD-YYYY')),
   PARTITION PROVISION_HIST_P2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('12-01-2014', 'MM-DD-YYYY')),
   PARTITION PROVISION_HIST_P3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-01-2015', 'MM-DD-YYYY'))
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX provision_hist_pk 
   ON PROVISION_HIST (card_nbr, provision_loc_cd, start_ts);
```

I JUST NEED TO INSERT SOME DUMMY DATA FOR TESTING.
SO I USED

```
INSERT INTO provision_hist (CARD_NBR,PROVISION_LOC_CD, START_TS,END_TS,LAST_UPDT_TS,PROVISION_META_DATA,UNPROVISION_META_DATA)
VALUES (4444,'lx',to_timestamp( '03/18/2012 02:35 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM'),to_timestamp( '12/01/2014 02:35 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM'),current_timestamp(6),'<Warehouse whono="200"><Building>Leased</Building> </Warehouse>','<Warehouse whono="200"> <Building>Leased</Building> </Warehouse>'
);
```

ORA-02290: check constraint (USER_VALID_TIME793C79) violated

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Is user_valid_time a function?

Comment: @Rika It looks just a user defined name for period data type to me .

Comment: Also is this Oracle or SQL?

Comment: Is it version 12.1.0.1.0 or 12.1.0.2.0? The USER_VALID_TIME793C79 is a system generated constraint that is created when you add temporal validity to the table. The constraint is supposed to ensure that you cannot enter invalid time period (like start_ts being > end_ts.) I have experienced bugs in certain 12.1.0.1.0 versions depending on whether you are in a CDB or non-CDB installation. Check if your "to_timestamp" values work correctly and your start_ts actually is < end_ts.

Comment: @KimBergHansen  I am on 12.1.0.1.0 . checked whether start_ts<end_ts sql shows good.

Comment: @Rika: your question doesn't make sense. Oracle uses SQL - in fact Oracle had the very first commercial implementation of SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle vs (MySQL, SQL Server) sometimes some people say SQL for short

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just displayed a variation of a known bug associated with Oracle 12c's [temporal validity](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_design.htm#ADFNS967) feature, [Bug 18195286 : ORA-2290 ON INSERT INTO TABLE WITH TEMPORAL VALIDITY](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?_afrLoop=3507605072480812&id=18195286&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=91gxdvu39_141).

Specifically, when one alters or creates a table with the `PERIOD FOR` clause, a constraint is created to validate the dates for the period:

```
PERIOD FOR user_valid_time (start_ts, end_ts)
```

The constraint created can be displayed by querying user_constraints. It will show this:

```
SELECT search_condition
FROM user_constraints
WHERE table_name = 'PROVISION_HIST'
```

Results in the constraint:

```
(start_ts < end_ts) and (VALID > 0)
```

Your insert statement throws an error with this constraint.

Kim Berg Hansen identified this earlier, I am just citing the actual bug.  This is identified as being fixed with version 12.1.0.2.

Comment: That's the bug I was thinking about, yes. The problem in my case was, that the virtual invisible column "VALID" always had a negative value in my environment.

Answer (score -1):

Just by looking at the Insert part the AM of the to_timestamp is bothering me. How about at least taking out AM because it looks like in http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_timestamp.php, they don't do that. So first lets take out that. Maybe you also want to change FOR to AS. And it seems that user_valid_time is a function because of the parameters it takes in, so I will recommend finding this function and checking its implementation. "http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions231.htm"